# CSS How to keep the section filled with a background image after the position transform

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanna keep the section filled with a background image after the position transform.
Using this code I get a white background from the body element.

```
<section><div class="firstpage"></div></section>

   .firstpage{
       position: absolute;
       background-image:url('https://i.ibb.co/HGSY9Rv/bcb.png');
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
     }



  $(".firstpage").mouseenter(function(){
$(".firstpage").animate({
 'background-position-x': '-200px',
});});

  $(".firstpage").mouseleave(function(){
$(".firstpage").animate({
 'background-position-x': '0px',
});});
```

https://codepen.io/gamegame/pen/NWMpJvy

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. Have you tried `background-repeat: repeat-x;` instead of `no-repeat`?

Answer (score 0):

make the bg image bigger in the width by using a calculation

the calculation is created by using native CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)/[`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

basically, we add the length of the animation to the width

so it will always overflow,

and this is correct since we have a `calc()` *(so it is responsive)*

so the animation works fine always bigger and smaller display

> `100% + 200px`
>
> > *(let's say if the width of your device is 550px, now this calcolation will be `550 + 200 = 750`)*

and there isn't any need for javascript for animation

because with `:hover` we can do the same / and `transition`

#### code example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden; /* for not see the scrollbar */
}

.firstpage {
  --x: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/HGSY9Rv/bcb.png");
  /* not use `attachment: fixed` here */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + var(--x));
  transition: background-position-x 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.firstpage:hover {
  background-position-x: calc(var(--x) * -1); /* 200px * -1 = -200px */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="firstpage"></div>
</section>
```